# Conflicting information about the version of Virtualbox guest additions that is running

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have VirtualBox 6.1.36 installed on Windows 10, and I'm using it to run two virtual machines, one with Xubuntu 18.04 and the other with Xubuntu 22.04. "Auto-resize guest display" works for both, but copy and paste works only for the first one, so I was thinking about reinstalling the Guest Additions, but I've realized that I don't even understand what version is installed.

[The manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing) says

> To view the extension packs that are currently installed, start the VirtualBox Manager, as shown in Section 1.6, “Starting Oracle VM VirtualBox”. From the File menu, select Preferences. In the window that displays, go to the Extensions category. This shows you the extensions which are currently installed, and enables you to remove a package or add a new package.

If I do it I see 6.1.36r152435, which is indeed what I think I installed, and what I would like to have.

But there's also [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1112102/) on Ask Ubuntu explaining how to check what version is being used:

> Open the Session Information window (either with Machine->Session Information or with <kbd>Host</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>)
> Select the Runtime Information tab.
> Look at the Guest Additions version number.

A user commented that this answer indicates what is running, and not simply what is installed, so this should be the best way to check it. I can't tell if it's true.

Anyway, if I check my two virtual machines with this method I see that one has 5.2.8_KernelUbuntu r120774, while the other has 6.0.0 r127566. So they are different, and neither corresponds to the version indicated by the first method.

Now:

1. Are the guest additions bound to Virtualbox (so there's only one version, regardless of how many VMs are running) or are they bound to each VM?
2. What version of the guest additions is really running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's easy to get confused about this.

Extensions are something completely different. It's an interface for extending VirtualBox with additional functionality. This is about the host and its virtualization capabilities. The main reason why extensions exist is separation of the open-source part of VirtualBox from its proprietary components, like USB 2.0 and 3.0 support (these are provided as a non-free extension which is only unpaid for non-commercial use).

Your host very likely has a Guest Additions ISO installed. The host doesn't run the Guest Additions software (obviously, because it's not a guest) but you can have the ISO on it. That ISO can be loaded into virtual CD drives to install Guest Additions on guest VMs.

On Windows the ISO is installed by default, so it will always be in the same version as the installed VortualBox. On Linux it comes in an additional package and may not be installed, but if it is, it will generally also match VirtualBox. It's also possible to download it on demand - newer versions of VirtualBox will ask you if you want to do that if it isn't present yet.

Guests can run any version of Additions and it doesn't necessarily have to match host, although a mismatch can cause some features to not work correctly. The method described on AskUbuntu is the correct way of checking which version is currently running.

There are generally two ways of installing Guest Additions: from the ISO (using the menu option) or as a package from OS's repository. I would generally recommend the former, because it is almost guaranteed to match the version you're running on the host, but if you have the packaged version and it's working fine, then there's no point in fixing something that isn't broken.

Comment: I installed the Guest Additions from the ISO, and now copy/paste works. Thanks a lot!